# UWP - Need to check if power adapter is connected

Tags: windows, uwp

I want to check if a power adapter is connected to my machine. How to implement this using UWP?

I tried using System.Windows but this does not work with UWP.
So please help.

Comment: What have you tried this far?  Any code? _Does not work with UWP_ so what is the problem/error or error you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PowerManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.power.powermanager) class to access [BatteryStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.power.batterystatus) which shows whether it is charging or not.

Simply use `PowerManager.BatteryStatus == Charging`

Comment: That's not it. You want to check the [`PowerSupplyStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.power.powersupplystatus) -- the device can be plugged in, but still not charging. It is typically dangerous to make any assumptions about the device just because it is connected to A/C power.

Comment: Can someone explain the difference between [`Windows.System.Power`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.power?view=winrt-22621) and [`Windows.Devices.Power`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.power?view=winrt-22621)? Specifically, when to use which?